# Use UpdateByQueryAsync to make a partial update in Elasticsearch using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have two tables in my database with a child/parent relationship and have created an Elasticsearch index that contains the combined list of records from the two tables. A parent record can have multiple records in its `Children` field. If I had two indices for the two tables and wanted to update each one partially, I would use this command using NEST:

```
await elasticClient.UpdateAsync<object>(id, u =>
                u.Index(indexName).Doc(updatedFieldsCollection)
            );
```

But the problem is my index is not a simple one and every parent has all its child records in its `children` field which is a list so when a record in my child table is updated I'm not sure how I can locate the entry in the Elasticsearch index and partially update it. The below query seems to identify the record I am looking for but unlike the above command, there is no `.Doc` method I could use to partially update the part of the index I am interested in (which is one of the child elements on the `Children` list):

```
await elasticClient.UpdateByQueryAsync<ChildParentModel>(u => u
                .Query(q => q
                    .Term(f => f
                        .Children.First().Uid, id)
                )
            );
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Updating the whole document is not available while you're using Update By Query API. Instead, you can use Script!
Read [documentaion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

Code :

```
var scriptParams = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"paramName", "newValue"}};
client.UpdateByQuery<ChildParentModel>(uq => uq
    .Query(q => q.Term(f => f.Children.First().Uid, id))
    .Script(s => s
        .Source("ctx._source.propertyName = params.paramName;")
        .Params(scriptParams)
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdi. I am not trying to update the whole document. Quite the opposite. I just need to update a part of a document. I have a dynamic object that contains the updated properties and their new values. I'm not sure how I can use the **Script** method to update those properties only. Also, the ScriptDescriptor object seems to have **Source()** and **Id()** methods only. I don't see any **Inline()** method as in your example. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @MarChal! I've updated my answer. Hope it works as you expected.

Comment: Thanks mate. I managed to get the update working but the problem is the update is done on the parent object's paramName (if it happens to have the same field). The reason is the query returns the parent that has a child with the provided id. I need to change the query such that it returns the child. What I mean is _source points to the parent document. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: @MarChal For example, if you have a class like this:  public class ParentClass
    {
        public ChildClass Child { get; set; }

    }
and     public class ChildClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    } you can easily access and update ChildClass.Name property using this : 
`ctx._source.child.name`

Comment: My scenario is a bit more complicated. The child field is actually an array and I'm supposed to update one single element of that array whose id matches the argument used in the query (id). I came up with this but it doesn't look quite neat to me:
`.Source("for (int j = 0; j < ctx._source.children.size(); j++){ if (ctx._source.children[j].uid == params.uid){ctx._source.children[j].name=params.name; ...; break;}}")`
I have multiple fields to update in that one item so I have to dynamically build the string to include all the updated fields. I hope there is a better way to do this though.

Comment: @MarChal could you share your parent and child classes?